# Simple Powershell and soap Syntax common language specification error

Tags: powershell, web-services, soap, wsdl

Im trying to get some metrics made available from a wsdl via Powershell so i can monitor a service. It seems to be a relatively simple process which makes my failing script all the more confusing, the request looks like the following;

```
$url = "<url>"
$webservice = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $url -UseDefaultCredential
$webservice | gm
```

the error i get looks like the following;

```
gm : The field or property: "Credentials" for type: 
"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy4ax_002_25286_file_Monitor_wsdl.MonitorService" differs only in 
letter casing from the field or property: "credentials". The type must be Common Language Specification (CLS) compliant.
At line:3 char:15
+ $webservice | gm
+               ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Member], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotACLSComplaintProperty,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetMemberCommand
```

Im relatively fresh to powershell and only have a basic understanding of CLS, can somone help me understand what im looking at?

Comment: Does the URI contains a reference to the Credentials parameter ? From the look of it, Powershell / C# interaction is breaking because somewhere in the Powershell there is a reference to "Credentials" but in your C# you have "credentials" (this is a casing issue) Powershell is case insensitive so it doesn't care but C# cares very much.

Comment: Yes, apologies i neglected to mention i spotted that. That does make sense, the resource contains an xml schema element that reference credentials and it is lower case.

<xs:element name="credentials" type="xs:base64Binary">
  <xs:annotation>
   <xs:documentation>proprietary header extension</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
 </xs:element>

That's useful, I cant change the source but i'm sure there's a way to transform the element in the pipe. I currently don't understand the C# interaction in this process, so any advice while i work this out would be happily received.